# Add clickable button on each node in jstree in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have list of value in object. I need to add button on each node in jstree.

My code :

This is static code which is working for single value.

```
$('#tree').jstree({
core:{
    data:[
        '<button>Press</button> One'
    ]
},
plugins:['checkbox']
```

});

but i want to add button dynamically to each node.

```
var arrayCollections = ${jsonArray};
$('#jstreesD').jstree({
    'core' : {

            ],
        'data' :[ arrayCollections,'<button>Press</button> Ok'],

    },
})

 <div id="jstreesD"></div>
```

but this is not working. 
Is there a way to do like this.

Thanks,
VJM

Comment: What is `jsonArray` and why are you trying to wrap it with `$()`. And anyway if it is an array you will get 'data: [["button", "button"], "button"]`. And I believe you need 'data': ['button', 'button']

Comment: hi Leguest thanks for reply, jsonArray contain data like this var arrayCollection = [ {
  "id" : "100",
  "parent" : "#",
  "text" : "MyData"
 },
{
   "id" : "155",
   "parent" : "MyData",
   "text" : "Test",
  },
});
i need to add button on each node

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try this:

```
    $(function () {

        var data =  [ { "id" : "100", "parent" : "#", "text" : "MyData" }, { "id" : "155", "parent" : "MyData", "text" : "Test", } ]

        $('#jstree').jstree({
            'core' : {
                'data' : data.map(function(item){

                    return "<button>Press</button>" + item.text
                })

            }
        });
    });
```

JSFiddle [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/69xnux2f/1/)

Comment: thanks, but in this way I get javascript exception 'Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined' and in screen only one button display without any data.

Comment: I solved that error but now data not display treeview format based on parent id, direct display as simple entry in screen with button.

Comment: I am not sure, I think you need reassemble your data, because jsTree looks for `children`, not for parentId

Comment: Yes may be, but without button my data display properly in jstreeview.

Comment: Create jsfiddle with your data, maybe I can help you

Comment: Lets work here (http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/zpshgp04/2/), because in your jsfiddle you did not add any libraries. Anyway even with your data, I don't think they are properly displayed

Comment: Yes data display properly in your jsfiddle, now I need this data with button, also current data not display in treeview. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Leguest, can you check http://jsfiddle.net/vkumar111/zpshgp04/15/ why getting undefined.

Comment: @VJM You can use the `data` field in the node to carry extra data - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23359311/2877364)